# update cart with php sessions

Tags: php, session

I am trying to update my cart quantity,my products are displayed with foreach loop .So, I tried  to update it through this code , it worked but only for the first item selected on addtocart submit . What is the problem ? how to make the update for each item on one update button click ?

```
if (isset($_POST["quansub"]) ){

    $itq = $_POST["itq"];
    $_SESSION["itq"] =  $itq;
    $_SESSION["incart"][$select]["item_quantity"]= $_SESSION["itq"];

    header("location:selecteditems.php");
}
```

Comment: Could you provide some more of the code, i.e the full foreach? It looks as though you are only setting the session for one item?

Comment: yeah the point I need to make  is setting the quantity for every item I want ...how ?

Comment: the full foreach only to display the items after adding them to cart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this the sort of thing you want?

I would suggest for each item in your cart have something like this:

```
<input type='hidden' name='quantity[1]' id='quantity[1]'>
<input type='hidden' name='quantity[2]' id='quantity[2]'>

foreach($_POST['item'] AS $key=>$value){
    $qty = $_POST["quantity"][$key];
    $_SESSION["quantity"][$key] =  $qty;
    $_SESSION["incart"][$select]["item_quantity"]= $_SESSION["quantity"][$key];
}
```

Where you have "$select", use it to do the following:

```
<input type="text" name="itq[<?= $select ?>]" value="<?php echo $val["item_quantity"]; ?>"/>
```

Then do the following in PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST["quansub"] && $_POST['itq'][$select])){
    $_SESSION["incart"][$select]["item_quantity"] = $_POST["itq"][$select];
}
```

Move this code outside of the foreach loop:

```
if (isset($_POST["quansub"])){
    header("location:selecteditems.php");
}
```

Having "quantity[1], quantity[2]" etc... makes it very easy to loop through the input values and get out their values. This is very useful when storing multiple items into a database that are using the same names.

Giving the names a unique "key" also means you can determine where they belong to in a database as well as you could give them the "key" by using their database or product id for example.

If you want me to explain individual parts to this let me know.

Comment: why did you use itq[1] tq[2]

Comment: It allows you to store multiple quantities into the session. It's just an example. If you had 2 product ids, 57 and 61 for example, you could have this as the session: $_SESSION['quantity'][57] = 22; $_SESSION['quantity'][61] = 10; It allows you to easily store them all together.

Comment: I tried it now,,itis updating all quantities at the same time

Comment: Isn't that what you want? Or it is making them all the same value?

Comment: I want to update each quantity alone ..on one submit ..i.e. : set quantity item  2 ..it will update it to 2 ..the other quantites will remain the same

Comment: Where is the $select variable coming from? Also, why are you setting the $_SESSION['itq'], why not just do this: $_SESSION["incart"][$select]["item_quantity"]= $itq;

Comment: the $select is coming from the first foreach loop which displays the items selected from add to cart.. I made it like that,,but it is updating only the first item added to cart

Comment: It's hard to understand exactly what's going on/going wrong without seeing the code. Could you provide more of the code in the question please?

Comment: The reason it's updating only the first product is because of the following: You have the loop running on page load, the first time the loop runs it sets the quantity and then goes to a different page. You are only setting a value on the first iteration of the loop, so it will only affect the first product.

Comment: so what you recommend me to do ?

Comment: Check again, sorry I added the comment before finishing.

Comment: so what you recommend me to do ?

Comment: I am receiving this error Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead)

Comment: but can you breifly explain what did you do ?

Comment: Sure, I'll add it into the answer. Would be nice if you could accept the answer as it worked :)

Comment: That error you was receiving, I believe it was because there was an error with my code as I missed a bracket in one of the if statements. Sorry for that!

Comment: I am new to stackoverflow what exactly do you want me to do  ""Would be nice if you could accept the answer as it worked :)""

Comment: this is not familiar tom me itq[<?= $select ?>] ,, it is confusing

Comment: Choose one answer that you believe is the best solution to your problem.
To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.
You may change which answer is accepted, or simply un-accept the answer, at any time.

Comment: <?= $select ?> is the same as <?php echo $select; ?> it's just the quick way of printing out php variables within html.